# SSIS OLE DB datasource Check row count

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package with a OLE DB source reading two columns from a table.  I need to check if the source table has some records and perform different actions based on whether the row count from source table is 0 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OLE DB Source is in a [Data Flow Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which handles one record at a time.  If you want to ask a question about the table as a whole, you should do that in the [Control Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137681%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), not in the Data Flow.

Create an [Execute SQL task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) in your control flow and use it to, for instance, count the number of records in a table, or the number of records that match a certain condition.  Then you can take other actions based on the [parameters and return codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

If you want to do Task A if your table has zero record, but Task B if it has more than zero records, then look at [adding expressions to the precedence constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) leading to Task A and Task B.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Execute SQL Task and in that you can count the number of records and assign it to a variable.

Then , you can use "Precedance Constraint Editor" and give the formula as "@[User::RecordCount]>1" do some other task.

Hope I answered your query.